# Unable to connect Mysql router using sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I am unable to connect Mysql router using sqoop and getting below error.
how to connect MySQL router 8 using sqoop.

while connect i am using router host and router port.
Command:

sqoop eval 
--connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx:8976/abcde 
--driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
--username "aabbcc" 
--password "qq2211ddff" 
--query "select * from fffgggsss limit 5"

Details:
mysql server: 8.0.16
mysql router version: 8.0.16
sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.5.115-3

20/11/18 18:06:31 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is` com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
20/11/18 18:06:32 WARN tool.EvalSqlTool: SQL exception executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'aabbcc'@'xxxxxxx' (using password: YES)

Comment: I can able to login manually MySQL with same user and password. but unable to login MySQL router using sqoop

Comment: Mysql router IP: 1.2.3.4.5
mysqlrouter port: 8976

sqoop eval
--connect jdbc:mysql://1.2.3.4.5:8976/abcde
--driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
--username "aabbcc"
--password "qq2211ddff"
--query "select * from fffgggsss limit 5"


We have configured 3 node innodb cluster and connect to Mysql db using mysql router.
same i am trying to connect using sqoop not getting connect.

please help me how to connect to MySQL router.

Comment: Looks Sqoop using jdbc connector . if its yes, jdbc connector does support mysql router connectivity ?

Comment: After debug, i suspect sqoop unable to trust SSL. looks this is certificate issue.

in log:

2020-12-07T19:15:01.348721+05:30          240 Connect   test_ro@10.999.333.99 on test_user using SSL/TLS
2020-12-07T19:15:01.348884+05:30          240 Connect   Access denied for user 'test_ro'@'10.999.333.99' (using password: YES)

Comment: Please help me , how sqoop handle SSL mysql connections?